# MVC ModelState validation failing for null value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

If I have the following model:

```
public class Model
{
    public int ModelID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

And the following controller method:

```
public ActionResult Create(Model model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.Created = DateTime.Now;

        // Save to DB
    }
}
```

In the view the Created field is hidden as I want this to populate with the timestamp of when the Create controller method is called. This fails ModelState validation due to the model.Created property being null.

I don't want to make the model.Created property Nullable but I need to somehow specify that this field isn't required in the view. Can someone please advise how to accomplish this?

Comment: move model.Created = DateTime.Now; outside the if.

Comment: I tried that but ModelState.IsValid still returns false.

Comment: what error does it give for being invalid? you can use VS property inspector to find the error.

Comment: ModelState.Values[2].Errors[0].ErrorMessage = "The Created field is required."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to exclude the `Created` property from binding using the `[Bind]` attribute, as follows:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Created")] Model model)
{
    ....
}
```

It is also recommended for security reasons, as you don't want your client to set `Created` value for you.